# How many covariate are too many?

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction, predictor

I have a sample size of 167.  In addition to DV, IV, and a moderator variable, I would like to use 6 variables.  Is it too many?  How do you determine acceptable numbers of covariates?

Also, fewer covariates can be a better study model or a worse model? I appreciate your opinions.

It is a hierarchical model, 1)covariates, 2)IV, moderator, 3)interaction.

Comment: How many parameters will the model estimate?

Comment: You could use Lasso or ridge regression to regularize complexity

Comment: What kind of model are you running?

Comment: Hierarchical linear regression with 3 steps, 1)covariates, 2) predictor, moderator, 3)interaction. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please write down the model you want to use?